# Passing a generic collection of objects to a method that requires a collection of the base type

Tags: c#, collections, casting, types

Say I have a method that is expecting a generic collection parameter of a base type, see **Test.MethodA(IEnumerable(BaseClass) listA)** below. How come when I pass it a collection of a derived type the code wont build? Wouldn't all instances of **DerivedClass** also be a **BaseClass**?

I could have just created a new **List(BaseClass)** and passed that to **MethodA(IEnumerable(BaseClass) listA)**. But I would think C# would be smart enough to know that a collection of DerivedClass has all the same properties as a collection of BaseClass.

Is using the List.Cast(T)() method as I've shown the best way to solve this problem?

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public int SomeField;
    public abstract string SomeAbstractField
    {
        get;
    }
}

class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public override string SomeAbstractField
    {
        get { return "foo"; }
    }
}

class TestClass
{ 

    public void MethodA(IEnumerable<BaseClass> listA)
    {

    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        List<DerivedClass> listB = new List<DerivedClass>();

        //Error 16  The best overloaded method match for 
        //TestClass.MethodA(List<BaseClass>)' 
        //has some invalid arguments
        this.MethodA(listB);

        //this works
        this.MethodA(listB.Cast<BaseClass>());
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a generic collection to base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539287/casting-a-generic-collection-to-base-type)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Cast<>()` is the best way to solve it at the moment. Your original version would work fine in C# 4.0 / .NET 4.0 though, where `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T`.

(I've just verified it compiles under .NET 4.0 beta 1.)

Until .NET 4.0 and C# 4 come out, generics are invariant - `IEnumerable<object>` and `IEnumerable<string>` are effectively unrelated interfaces. Even in .NET 4.0, you wouldn't be able to do this with `List<T>` as the parameter type - only interfaces and delegates will be variant, and even then only when the type parameter is *only* used in appropriate positions (output positions for covariance, input positions for contravariance).

To learn more about variance in C# 4, read Eric Lippert's excellent [series of blog posts](https://ericlippert.com/category/covariance-and-contravariance/) about it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you're the best. I knew the answer, but you've entered it faster. @Downvoter: why the downvote?

Comment: @Jon that was me.  Apparently I can no longer be trusted to click on the correct arrow.  I only noticed because I saw my rep go down and wondered who down voted me.

Comment: Downvoted by Microsoft... now I've really got to worry. I guess it's time to tear up my chapter on variance and start again ;)

Comment: @Jon, I would attribute the down vote to the performance bugs I'm working through today.  They've made me click happy.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case (i.e. for collections that are modifiable), it is NOT the case that "a collection of DerivedClass has all the same properties as a collection of BaseClass": into a collection of Fruit you can insert Banana, Apple and Pear -- in a collection of Orange, you can't, so, you see, it *doesn't* have the same properties (under modification).

IEnumerable is a different case, since it's NOT modifiable, as as @Jon says this excessive restriction has been removed for that special case in 4.0.