# How to cast a generic collection to an generic collection of ancestors?

Tags: c#, generics

Consider a list of `Label`:

```
Collection<Label> labels = new Collection<Label>();
```

Now i want to cast this to a collection of `Controls`:

```
public void ScaleControls(ICollection<Control> controls) {}
```

i would try calling:

```
ScaleControls(labels);
```

but that doesn't compile.

```
ScaleControls((ICollection<Control>)labels);
```

compiles, but crashes at runtime.

```
ICollection<Control> controls = (ICollection<Control>)labels;
ScaleControls(c);
```

compiles, but crashes at runtime.

Is there a way to pass around generic lists of objects?

---

The alternative is to abandon generic lists, and use typed lists:

```
public class ControlList : Collection<Control>
{
}

pubic void InvalidateControls(ControlList controls)
{
}
```

But that means all code using generics must be retrofitted.

Comment: what version of .Net do you use?

Comment: Does the collection have to originally be of type Label or could you get away with Control since label inherits from Control?

Comment: You should read up on covariance and contravariance, that could solve your problem. Sadly few if any of the build-in collections are using it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i have a vague understanding on what they are; but only in the context of "What you want to do is not supported in CLR yet because of...covariance and contravariance." By 'solve my problem' do you mean that i'll realize that i cannot do what i want - so no problem. Or is there a way to solve the problem if i read more about covariance and contravariance.

Comment: @w0lf .NET Framework 3.5

Comment: Unfortunately, covariance and contravariance are supported starting with .NET 4.0, so I guess you'll have to settle for one of the less elegant solutions.

Comment: @Ian I think some of the material that is out there around covariance and contravariance explains why you shouldn't, from a type safety perspective, be able to do what you are asking to do. The gist is that if you were allowed to do what you're asking, then you could potentially write code to add a TextBox control to a List<Label> collection, which is totally invalid.

Comment: In formal terms, since `Label` < `Control`, we have that `Collection<Label>` < `ICollection<Control>`, and passing a more generic type to a function expecting the more specific type isn't type safe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a generic collection to base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539287/), [Passing a generic collection of objects to a method that requires a collection of the base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174328/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't cast it; you have to convert it yourself.

```
InvalidateControls(new List<Control>(labels));  //C# 4 or later
```

Your problem here is that `ICollection<T>` is not covariant.  The reason ICollection is not covariant is to prevent methods like this from being evil:

```
void AddControl(ICollection<Control> controls, Control control)
{
    controls.Add(control);
}
```

Why would that be evil?  Because if ICollection were covariant, the method would allow you to add TextBoxes to lists of labels:

```
AddControl(new List<Label>(), new TextBox());
```

`List<Control>` has a constructor that takes `IEnumerable<Control>`.  Why can we pass `labels` in?  Because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant: You can't put anything into an `IEnumerable<T>`; you can only take things out.  Because of that, you know that you can treat anything retrieved from the `IEnumerable<T>` as a T (of course) *or any of its base types*.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you're using .Net 3.5.  In that case, `IEnumerable<T>` is not covariant, and you'll need more code to convert the collection.  Something like this:

```
ICollection<T> ConvertCollection<T, U>(ICollection<U> collection) where U : T
{
    var result = new List<T>(collection.Count);
    foreach (var item in collection)
        result.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: `Cast` returns an `IEnumerable`, rather than the `ICollection` required by this hypothetical example.

Comment: i don't see why the it's not a solvable problem: `controls.Add(new HttpWebRequst());`   *ArgumentException - cannot add type `HttpWebRequest` to `ICollection<Label>`*

Comment: @IanBoyd yes I noticed that about IEnumerable, and have corrected it.

Comment: I think the point would be that trading away compilation time errors for runtime errors is not the "C# way" to do things.

Comment: @IanBoyd I don't understand your question: the compiler is telling you that you can't add an HttpWebRequest to a collection of labels because HttpWebRequest does not descend from `Label`.  Would you expect any different?

Comment: Does `new List<Control>(labels)` point back to the original list? If i add/edit/delete items in `controls` will the changes be reflected in `labels`?

Comment: @phoog It's only a problem if i add the wrong thing. In reality i won't add the wrong thing, because my method is documented that it will not add the wrong things.

Comment: @IanBoyd 1) `new List<Control>(labels)` creates a new list and copies the references.  But that call won't work in .NET 3.5.  2) Your method may be documented that it won't add the wrong things, but the compiler doesn't know that.  The compiler only allows covariant conversions that can be proven always to be type safe.

Comment: @IanBoyd who verifies that the documentation is correct? I've yet to work on a project where all the documentation was correct and where all the methods with correct documention had no bugs

Comment: @IanBoyd: also, just because it's documented doesn't mean a programmer will a) read the documentation or b) forget. That's what type safety is for.

Comment: No need to throw out usability for type safety. Turns out the problem is solvable (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8810701/12597), Microsoft just hasn't applied it to generics yet.

Comment: Accepted for "not possible". Workaround: Tell the compiler to do what i want anyway (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8810701/12597)

Comment: From this answer I was able to deduce that I need to add a constructor to my collection object with a single parameter of `IEnumerable<MyType>` and that made my error go away.

Answer (score 4):

A quick answer to the question:

```
labels.Cast<Control>().ToList()
```

This will create an entirely new, separate list, so if you were to pass the new collection to a method that adds a control to it, then that new control will not be reflected in the original collection, `labels`.

An alternative is to look at the method that you're passing the collection to.  Suppose you have a method such as the following:

```
    void AddControl(List<Control> controls, string controlName)
    {
        Control ctrl = this.FindControlByName(controlName);

        controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
```

You cannot pass a `List<Label>` object to this method, but you can if you rewrite it as a generic method, as shown below:

```
    void AddControl<T>(List<T> controls, string controlName)
        where T : Control
    {
        Control ctrl = this.FindControlByName(controlName);

        controls.Add((T)ctrl); // a cast is required
    }
```

Granted, the above suggestions may not be possible or preferrable, depending on your situation.

As indicated in your own answer, yet another possibility is to utilzie the non-generic interfaces.  This is a perfectly valid approach; I think that ever since generics came out in .NET 2.0 we've generally become averse to casting, thinking that it is somehow "bad", but sometimes casting is simply necessary when dealing with polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found - stop using `Collections`:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
```

and then the method becomes:

```
public void ScaleControls(IList controls) {}
```

I get the benefit of a generic lists, without .NET complaining that it cannot do the obvious.

And if someone calls:

```
controls.Add(new System.Xml.XmlDocument());
```

then I get the error:

> **ArgumentException**
> The value "System.Xml.XmlDocument" is not of type "System.Windows.Forms.Label" and cannot be used in this generic collection.

Exactly as I would expect.

Comment: Good example for **XY Problem**  http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Comment: @L.B. i know, i know. My question asked "How to cast to an ancestor." The answer that i'll have to accept is "you can't". i could ask a separate question, "How can i do what i want, given that it's not possible" - but no need to open an entirely new question when the answer's here.