# In C#, what is the recommended way to cast a List of Interface to a list of objects?

Tags: c#, collections, casting

I have code that returns and array of IVehicle interface

```
  IEnumerable<IVehicle> allVehicles = GetAllVehicles();
```

and I know that all of these objects are Car objects.  What is the right way to cast

```
IEnumerable<IVehicle>
```

to

```
IEnumerable<Car>
```

as i need to pass these into another function that requires `<Enumerable<Car>`

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810370/how-to-cast-a-generic-collection-to-an-generic-collection-of-ancestors

Comment: Have a look at `OfType<Car>()` and `Cast<Car>()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast it like this:

```
var allCars = allVehicles.Cast<Car>();
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's possible, due to the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>` that `allVehicles` in fact already is an `IEnumerable<Car>`. `Cast` considers the opportunity for optimising the whole operation into a single cast this implies.

Comment: That is *not* casting the collection at all.  It's creating an entirely new collection based on casting the items in it.  That's *completely* different.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if that's actually what's needed, but it can be done using a Linq extension method as follows.

```
IEnumerable<Car> Cars = allVehicles.Cast<Car>();
```

However this will throw an exception if one of the members in `allVehicles` is *not* a `Car`; if desired, this can be circumvented as follows.

```
IEnumerable<Car> Cars = allVehicles.OfType<Car>().Cast<Car>();
```

Comment: You don't need to call `Cast` on the results of `OfType`

Comment: @JonHanna Thanks for the remark, I wasn't aware of that.