# Passing Collection of Inherited Objects to Method Accepting an ICollection of Base Objects

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, icollection, generic-collections

Background:  I have a generic collection of type `DirectoryCollection<T>` and have specified that T must be of type `IEntity`.  I have a concrete type `Entity` which implements `IEntity` and two derived types, `Employee` and `Station`.

In .NET 4.0 I know that it is possible ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174328/passing-a-generic-collection-of-objects-to-a-method-that-requires-a-collection-o)) to call a method with an `IEnumerable<Entity>` parameter as `DirectoryCollection<Employee>`, however, it seems that does not work for a method with a parameter of type `ICollection<Entity>`.  In said method, I use the `Remove` and `Add` methods of the collection and consequently, am hesitant to put `IEnumerable` into the method signature.

What is the best practice in solving this problem?

Comment: Does `DirectoryCollection` implement `ICollection`?  I am guessing not?

Comment: @ChrisShain not `ICollection`, but it does implement `ICollection<T> where T : IEntity`

Comment: @MichaelKingsmill and you can't make it `ICollection<in T> where T : IEntity`, presumably as T is an input and output type...?

Comment: @SamHolder `ICollection<T>` is a framework interface; it's not possible to change the variance notation on the type parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `ICollection` in the `DirectoryCollection` class.  You may need to implement it explicitly, due to the covariance restriction that @SamHolder mentions in the comments.  See [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on implementaing an interface explicitly.

Furthermore, in the methods that accept `ICollection<Entity>` as a parameter, you may need to change the signature to accept `ICollection<IEntity>` instead.

Comment: My issue turned out to be unrelated to the generic collection, but your suggested steps were sufficient for getting the generic collection passed to the method.  Thanks!