# Generic type of a class cannot accept generic type of derived type of the class

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting List<> of Derived class to List<> of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class)

The title may not make good sense. See the code:

```
class Person {}

class Manager : Person {}

class PaymentCalculator<T> where T : Person
{
    public double Calculate(T person)
    {
        return 0;    // calculate and return
    }
}

class Calculators : List<PaymentCalculator<Person>>
{
    public Calculators()
    {
        this.Add(new PaymentCalculator<Person>());
        this.Add(new PaymentCalculator<Manager>());     // this doesn't work

        PassCalculator(new PaymentCalculator<Person>());
        PassCalculator(new PaymentCalculator<Manager>());   // this doesn't work
    }

    public void PassCalculator(PaymentCalculator<Person> x)
    { }
}
```

The two lines in the code marked as "this doesn't work" won't compile.

I can work around the issue, but it doesn't seem my intent is wrong. Or, is it?

Comment: this question gets asked way too often with way too many different variations. we need a "covariance does not work that way in C#" close reason :)

Comment: I like my question more than the other question! (Also I really like and appreciate the answer from Thomas and ie.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `Manager` inherits from `Person`, `PaymentCalculator<Manager>` doesn't inherit from `PaymentCalculator<Person>`. It would work if `PaymentCalculator<T>` was [contravariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), but classes can't be contravariant in .NET (only interfaces and delegates can be contravariant).

A possible solution to your problem would be to declare a contravariant interface like this:

```
interface IPaymentCalculator<in T> // "in" means contravariant
{
    double Calculate(T person);
}
```

Make `PaymentCalculator<T>` implements the `IPaymentCalculator<T>` interface:

```
class PaymentCalculator<T> : IPaymentCalculator<T> where T : Person
{
    public double Calculate(T person)
    {
        return 0;    // calculate and return
    }
}
```

And make the `Calculators` class inherit from `List<IPaymentCalculator<Person>>`

```
class Calculators : List<IPaymentCalculator<Person>>
```

With these changes, it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

That is right. "By default" `new MyClass<Derived>()` is not assignable to `new MyClass<Base>()`. But you can do the trick using [co-variance of interfaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx):

```
class Person { }

class Manager : Person { }

interface IPaymentCalculator<out T> where T : Person
{
}

class PaymentCalculator<T> : IPaymentCalculator<T> where T : Person
{
    public double Calculate(T person)
    {
        return 0;    // calculate and return
    }
}

class Calculators : List<IPaymentCalculator<Person>>
{
    public Calculators()
    {
        this.Add(new PaymentCalculator<Person>());
        this.Add(new PaymentCalculator<Manager>());     // this doesn't work

        PassCalculator(new PaymentCalculator<Person>());
        PassCalculator(new PaymentCalculator<Manager>());   // this doesn't work
    }

    public void PassCalculator(IPaymentCalculator<Person> x)
    { }
}
```

This will compile and work.

Comment: In this case it's contravariance, not covariance (I initially made the same mistake...)

Comment: BTW, we came up with the exact same solution... I'll leave my answer anyway because it gives more explanations ;)