# Casting Generic IList<T> of derived type to base type with a desirable Object Oriented Design, if needed

Tags: c#, oop, generics, c#-4.0, design-patterns

I have this code and I have a compile error because of the Covariance. 
How can I resolve this problem, I need my `SelectAll` method return  `IList<Entity>`.

I want Some of my Entities inherit of an Abstract class and in the other classes, I could use the abstract class to do things. What is the best way to change my design to achieve this?

```
public interface IEntities
{    
    IList<IEntities> SelectAll();
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntities
{
    public abstract IList<IEntities> SelectAll();
}

public class Server : Entity
{
    public IList<Entity> SelectAll()
    {
        return new IList<Server>();   // Compile Error 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038125/covariance-in-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817300/convert-listderivedclass-to-listbaseclass) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class) posts for relevant discussion. `IList<T>` is *not* covariant.

As you have seen, this doesn't work

```
var strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
List<object> objects = strings; //compilation error
```

Your options at a glance:

```
var strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

List<object> objects1 = strings.ConvertAll(s => (object)s); //List<T> method
List<object> objects2 = strings.Cast<object>().ToList(); //IEnumerable extension
List<object> objects3 = strings.Select(s => (object)s).ToList(); //plain Linq
```

For example, using `string` and `object` as derived and base class.

**Note**

This is allowed though

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new List<string> { "x", "y", "z" };
IEnumerable<object> objects = strings; //works
```

Because, `IEnumerable<T>` is `covariant` and it's actually `IEnumerable<out T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate an interface (IList is an interface).

You have to instantiate something that implements IList, such as list or array.

Like this:

```
return new List<Server>();
```

or:

```
return new Server[] { };
```

The functionality available externally will be only what IList declares, without the extra members of the type you actually implement.