# What is wrong with this design of RPG game effect system or how may I remove all particular effects from a list of different lists of derived effects?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

I guess I've run into a design issue... which I'm not sure how to solve myself. So sorry, but I have to provide some basic design info...

A game. Players, monsters, objects, different things may be under different effects:

```
public interface IEffect {}
```

There may be different particular Effects:

```
public interface IResistanceBuff : IEffect
{
    void modifyIncomingDamage(Damage damage);
}

public interface IDamageBuff : IEffect
{
    void modifyOutgoingDamage(Damage damage);
}
```

Why this way? Well, the concept it to avoid duplicating code. For example, this way I can unify damage reductions from type resistances and, for example, wearing armor. Simply, I make the `Type` class and the `Armor` class implement `IResistanceBuff`. (Similarily, the `Weapon` class will implement `IDamageBuff`).

But some effects are temporary, not permanent. For this, we will have:

```
public interface ITemporaryEffect : IEffect
{
    long TimeRemaining {get; set;}
}
```

Again, the purpose here is to avoid duplicating code. For example, the `PotionOfMight` class will implement `IDamageBuff` interface and derive from `Potion` abstract class, which in turn will implement `ITemporaryEffect` interface. Or, we will have `IStun` interface, which will implement `ITemporaryEffect`.

Now every object that can be under certain effects will store a collection (`HashSet` maybe?) of all effects it is under. This is to be able to more easily call these effects. For example, a character will have a property `public HashSet<IResistanceBuff> ResistanceBuffs {get; private set;}` and so we can make a character's `TakeDamage` method look like this:

```
void TakeDamage(Damage damage)
{
    this.ResistanceBuffs.ForEach(resistanceBuff =>
        resistanceBuff.modifyIncomingDamage(damage)
    );

    this.HP -= damage.Amount;

    if(this.HP <= 0) {
        this.Faint();
    }
}
```

But here comes the problem. I want to have one piece of code to update the remaining duration of temporary effects and remove those whose duration has expired.

My ([not working, by design of C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class)) idea for that was to make the `Character` class (and any other class that represents an object that can be under any sort of `Effect` - that means even `WorldMap`, because I thought I'd store weather conditions as `Effects` applied to the world) implement `IEffectStorage` interface:

```
public interface IEffectStorage
{
    List<HashSet<IEffect>> AllEffects {get;}
}

public class Character : IEffectStorage
{
    // ...
    public HashSet<IResistanceBuff> ResistanceBuffs {get; private set;}
    public HashSet<IDamageBuff> DamageBuffs {get; private set;}
    // ...
    public List<HashSet<IEffect>> AllEffects =>
        new List<HashSet<IEffect>> {ResistanceBuffs, DamageBuffs, /* ... */};
}
```

Now dealing with temporary effect expiration would be the responsibility of the `Effect` static class:

```
public static class Effect
{
    public static void ExpireTemporaryEffects(IEffectStorage effectStorage)
    {
        effectStorage.AllEffects.ForEach(effectSet =>
        {
            var effects = effectSet.ToList();
            effects.ForEach(effect =>
            {
                if(effect is ITemporaryEffect) {
                    effect.TimeRemaining--;
                    if(effect.TimeRemaining <= 0) {
                        effectSet.Remove(effect);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But, of course, as I said, I cannot do this.

Now I may start looking for some hackish and/or ugly ways to make this design working. ALtervatively, I may reason that I'm likely trying to do something against the design of the C# programming language and/or OO programming paradigm because of my failure to understand this paradigm well enough... Especially since this is the first project of this size I'm doing on my own, I choose to do the latter... So I'm asking this question :) Is my design all wrong and if yes, then how to fix it?

Sorry for the length of this post, but I feel all information above is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a game developer or have experience with game engines but I think most games or engines use something like frames as a meassure for time (maybe I am totally wrong on this). My Idea would be to change your ITemporaryEffect to

```
public interface ITemporaryEffect : IEffect
{
    bool IsActive(long currentFrame)
}
```

And implement it as follows:

```
public class SilencedEffect : ITemporaryEffect 
{
    private long duration = 1000;
    private long endFrame;

    public SilencedEffect(int currentFrame)
    {
        endFrame = currentFrame + duration;
    }

    public bool IsActive(long currentFrame)
    {
        return endFrame > currentFrame;
    }
}
```

This way you could iterate over it in your character or worldmap class and remove it if isn't is active anymore.

```
public class Character
{
    private IList<ITemporaryEffect> temporaryEffect;         

    public void UpdateEffects(long currentFrame)
    {
        var outdatedTempEffects = temporaryEffect.Where(p => !p.IsActive(currentFrame));
        temporaryEffects.RemoveRange(outdatedTempEffects);
    }
}
```