# List of interface D that implements interface B Can't be recognized as List<B>

Tags: c#

I have an interface ID, which is derived from another interface IB.

```
public interface IB
{
    int Num { get; }
}

public interface ID : IB
{

}
```

Let's say we have a class that implements ID:

```
public class DImpl : ID
{
     public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

I know that I can call a function that receives IB with a variable that is held as ID.

```
public void FuncOfIB(IB b)
{
     // do something
}

public static void Main()
{
     ID d = new DImpl();
     FuncOfIB(d); // Works
}
```

I would like to call a function that receives a `List<IB>` as a parameter:

```
void ProcessListOfIB(List<IB> list)
{
   // Some code
}
```

But it seems that I can't call this function with `List<ID>`.

```
public static void Main()
{
     List<ID> listID = new List<ID>();
     ProcessListOfIB(listID); // Doesn't work
}
```

Does anyone know why? And how can I fix it? thank you.

Edit: I need the function `ProcessListOfIB` to remove an item from the list, so copying doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting List<> of Derived class to List<> of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class)

Comment: You can workaround this with linq: `listD.Cast<IB>().ToList()`

Comment: The problem is that I want the function ProcessListOfIB() will delete a member in the original list. I'll edit my original post

Comment: A `List` allows you to add items, so potentially `ProcessListOfIB` could call `list.Add(x)`, where `x` is of type `IB`. This would mean your list would no longer be entirely composed of `ID` items. That in a nutshell is why the implicit cast is not permitted.

Comment: Well, does the code in your ProcessListOfIB method really require a List<T>? Could it perhaps be happy with a method parameter of type IEnumerable<T> instead? If your ProcessListOfIB method could work with an IEnumerable<T> instead of a List<T>, then use a method parameter using IEnumerable<T>. Not only would the method be usable with other collection types this way, your problem would simply disappear due to the generic type parameter in IEnumerable<T> being [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: I need to remove an item from the original list, so IEnumerable<T> doesn't help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create Generic method and limit type to IB:

```
void ProcessListOfIB<T>(List<T> list) where T:IB
{
    // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to loop through the collection (as opposed to modify it):

```
void ProcessListOfIB(IEnumerable<IB> list)
{
    // Some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List is not marked neither covariant nor contravariant (as it cannot be, it's not an interface), so that's why it doesn't work.