# Mocking methods that return IEnumerable types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am running into this issue in a somewhat larger context, but when condensed to the bare minimum, the question that remains is why does Moq not return the type specified  <s>in the interface</s>  for mocked methods? IEnumerable and List come back as empty arrays,
When I specifically call Setup with a return value, it changes, at least in the example below.

```
    public interface ITestTarget    {
        public IEnumerable<int> getSomeData();
    }

    public class TestTarget : ITestTarget    {
        public List<int> getSomeData() {return new List<int>() { 1 };  }
    }

    public class MockTest     {
        [Fact]
        public void TestMe()
        {
            var testMock = new Mock<ITestTarget>();
            var someResult = testMock.Object.getSomeData();

            Assert.IsType<Int32[]>(someResult);    // Why does this pass? someResult is an Integer array!

            testMock.Setup(m => m.getSomeData()).Returns(new List<int> { });   // forcing it to a list

            someResult = testMock.Object.getSomeData();

            Assert.IsType<List<int>>(someResult);    // Now it is a list
        }
    }
```

My real issue is that Moq seems to return an empty array even when I specifically set it up with an empty List (of a complex type), but I will ask that question later.

**Update and Re-phrasing my question**

I had not considered the fact that an array IS an IEnumerable, my Interface has IEnumerable, and that therefore what Moq returns is not wrong. When I change the interface to List, the Mock returns a List.

I am not ready to change the return types in my code. I can custom-tweak my assertions to deal with either type, but:

I am writing unit tests for an API with many endpoints that do similar things. I am trying to generizie my assertion code in a base class, and I just don't always know if I am dealing with an array or a List.

How can I resolve this? Should I avoid using IEnumerable as return types altogether?

Comment: After edit the question is still quite strange - if you require method to return list - its return type should be a flavor of a list (`List<T>` not even `IList<T>` or `IReadonlyList<T>`, definitly not `IEnumerable<T>`) otherwise it can return whatever type satisfies the contract... Asserting that particular type returned when interface is enough only makes sense in tiny amount of cases (i.e. you want to confirm that internal types never returned directly and only via wrappers)

Comment: Alexei, I am asserting the types only to illustrate that they are different. Problem is, when the type is wrapped into an ObjectResult of an API's ActionResult, I cannot access the value if I don't cast it correctly. In other words, 

            List<T> actual = ((ObjectResult)actionResult.Result).Value as List<T>;

is null when Value comes back as an array.

Comment: Maybe you should ask actual question instead - I'm not sure what exactly you want to test and I'm pretty sure code shown in the post does not show the problem you actually have... (check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class which I suspect what your actual problem is... or maybe not... )

Comment: @cdonner why not just cast to `IEnumerable<T>` i.e. `IEnumerable<T> actual = ((ObjectResult)actionResult.Result).Value as IEnumerable<T>`? and maybe calling `ToList` on the result.

Comment: tada! and the award goes to:  @Guru (I was missing System.Linq).

Comment: I Agree with Alexei; it's not clear what you actually want to do. If your interface specifies an IEnumerable, then you should not be making any assumptions about the specific type.

Comment: @Plasmadog it is all clear now, thanks to some of the other comments. I made an assumption about the type of an IEnumerable when I shouldn't have, and that's what gave me a problem with asserting the result of a unit test. By casting it back to IEnumerable before doing anything with it, the type ambiguity was resolved.

Comment: I'm glad you have that sorted, but I wonder if you might have introduced a new one by casting to IEnumerable. Those conversions may be obscuring the intention of the test. Again, it's not clear what you actually want to test, but most assertion frameworks allow you to make assertions about collections that are type-agnostic, and which also tend to better express your intentions. Using one of those might be a better solution.
See the NUnit [Collection constraints](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/constraints/Constraints.html#collection-constraints) for example.

Comment: I am good, done for the day, code checked in ;-)  No bigger issues to worry about.
All I was trying to do was assert that my test returned some object in a list. I discovered that when there is no return value setup, you can get a "whatever" IEnumerable from Moq. What I have also run into is not resetting my mock, not hitting the intended setup because of overly specified parameter combinations, and thus getting an empty array when I had actually set up an empty List (but the Setup wasn't invoked). This confused me for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the comments, but I hate to have this question float around without a formal answer, so allow me to recap:

```
public interface ITestTarget    {
    public ⚠️IEnumerable<int>⚠️ getSomeData();
}

public class TestTarget : ITestTarget     {
    public ⚠️List<int>⚠️ getSomeData() {return new List<int>() { 1 };  }
}

var testMock = new Mock<ITestTarget>();
var someResult = testMock.Object.getSomeData();

// someResult can be any type that implements IEnumerable. We cannot make
// any further assumptions. My code assumed a List.
```

What matters to the Mock is the type in the Interface, not the implementation. Thus, if no specific return type is given through a setup, you cannot make an assumption about the type that the Mock returns. In my case, the defaut was an array. This made code invalid that attempted to access the result as a List (not in my example here).

Casting it to an `IEnumerable<T>` and using `ToList()`, as suggested by @Guru Stron, resolves the type ambiguity and made it work for either case - a Setup that explicitely returns a `List<T>` or the Mock default that returns an empty `<T>[]`.

This really had nothing to do with Moq or unit testing but with using types and interfaces correctly. Now that I understand that, I can illustrate my misunderstanding differently:

```
    int[] a = {1,2,3};

    List<int> d = (List<int>)a;     // can't do that!
    
    List<int> c = (a as IEnumerable<int>).ToList();     // do this!
```

Now you may say: There are a lot of words in this post (and bandwidth needed to download them) to come to a rather trivial conclusion. I am going to downvote the question and this answer, but let me ask you this: did you know that Moq returns an array type for IEnumerables if no setup is given with another type?