# c# - generic dictionary key, value inheritance problem

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics, .net-core

I have a method like this:

```cs
public void SomeMethod(Dictionary<IFoo, IBar> myDict) {}
```

and I have two classes that inherit from IFoo and IBar:

```cs
public class FooClass : IFoo {}
public class BarClass : IBar {}
```

I'm trying to use my method with a dictionary like below:

```cs
Dictionary<FooClass, BarClass> myDict = DeserializeFromJson();
SomeMethod(myDict);
```

But I'm getting the compile error

> argument cannot convert from ... to ... ".

Can someone explain why such conversion is invalid?

Comment: Suppose `SomeMethod` started with `myDict[new OtherFoo()] = new OtherBar();` where `OtherFoo : IFoo` and `OtherBar : IBar`. How would you expect that to work when your `Dictionary<FooClass, BarClass>` expects all keys to be `FooClass` and all values to be `BarClass`?

Comment: You mention inheritance, but looks like inheritance plays no role here, if you are using standard .net naming conventions you are working with interfaces

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this question about converting from `List<Dog>` to `List<Animal>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3720751/5133585) for *why* you can't do this directly. Here's the dictionary-specific explanation, imagine that you can do:

```
// here, myDict is of type Dictionary<Foo, Bar>, as we are outside SomeMethod
// suppose myDict is empty initially
SomeMethod(myDict);
```

And then `SomeMethod` could do:

```
// here, myDict is of type Dictionary<IFoo, IBar>, as we are inside SomeMethod
myDict.Add[new AnotherClass1(), new AnotherClass2());
```

where

```
class AnotherClass1: IFoo {}
class AnotherClass2: IBar {}
```

After `SomeMethod` returns, you do:

```
// here, myDict is Dictionary<Foo, Bar> again, we are outside SomeMethod
Bar firstValue = myDict.Values.First();
```

Wait... `firstValue` should be of type `AnotherClass2`!

See the problem?

Rather than creating a new `Dictionary<IFoo, IBar>` with the same values,

```
Dictionary<IFoo, IBar> newDict = myDict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

which could take some time (and the modifications to the dictionary that `SomeMethod` does won't reflect not the original dictionary), you can also make `SomeMethod` generic:

```
public void SomeMethod<TFoo, TBar>(Dictionary< TFoo, TBar> myDict) 
    where TFoo: IFoo
    where TBar: IBar 
{
    // the method can be implemented the same way as before
}
```