# Why can't I return T in a Generic<T> method?

Tags: c#, generics

The following code says I cannot return an object of type Certification? Why not as that is the definition of T?

```
public T BuildList<T>(T list, AttributeModel model) where T : Certification
{
    return new Certification("", "", "");
}
```

**Update:**

I was asked to explain why I think this should work. Fair question.

I read "where T : Certification" to mean that the method can also be read as:

```
public Certification BuildList(Certification list, AttributeModel model)
```

and so, it should require returning an object of type Certification. I'm obviously not understanding something basic about generics here - what do I have wrong?

**Update 2:**

I tried the following per @DStanley - this also won't compile:

```
public class Animal
{

    public T BuildList<T>(T list, AttributeModel model) where T : Animal
    {
        return new Animal();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you return a `Certification`, why not mark your method as returning a `Certification`? Why do you need generics here?

Comment: @Jimi That won't work, because `new()` is only for parameterless constructors.

Comment: Is Certification a real class or actually just some base type like an abstract class or an interface? And you actually want something derived from Certification. Then this begins to make sense to a certain degree. But then we are back to new T() and the need for a default constructor.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Right, I didn't even look at it. You could return `new T() { Param = "", ... };` (if possible and if there's a parameter-less constructor). But it actually doesn't look like this needs to be generic as it stands

Comment: @Ralf even if `Certification` is an abstract class or an interface, you can still declare the method to return `Certification`, and then in the implementation return any object from a class derived from it.

Comment: return (T)new Certification("", "", "");

Comment: @wohlstad i think i didn't contradict what you said. But maybe my wording was suboptimal?

Comment: @Mufaka yes but does that make sense in any context?

Comment: @Ralf I thought you meant that if it's an abstact class or an interface you can see the need to make the method generic etc. (like the OP attempted). And as I wrote I didn't see the need for that (following the 1st comment by Etienne de Martel
). Maybe I misunderstood your meaning.

Comment: _**Factory method pattern**_ is what you want. Unfortunately, C# doesn't (yet) support it directly through constraints, since the "**new()**" constraint can not have parameters, as of .NET 2.0. Maybe one day it can.

Comment: @Mufaka What happens when you call `BuildList<MyCertification>()`?

Comment: @Ralf Certification is a real class.

Comment: Note that if you are looking for actually constructing a list as name of the method imply - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class

Comment: On the "Update:" (which should not be added that way - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255644/should-edit-in-edits-be-discouraged) - yes, you completely misunderstood the meaning of `T : Certification`... Unfortunately, I don't know how to explain that - maybe reading through answers/links could be helpful.... or MSDN samples (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)...

Comment: The root cause you're missing is covariant and contravariant in generics.

Comment: My attempt at explaining what I think you misunderstood (which I could misunderstood too :) ): type restrictions give compiler *more information* about the type, but don't change type (which is `T`) itself.

Comment: @DStanley it fails because Certification isn't assignable to MyCertification. MyCertification is a Certification but Certification isn't a MyCertification. But T isn't a Certification either, it's a generic wrapper that is assignable to Certification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the constraint says that `T` *derives from* `Certification`. It does not say that `T` *is* `Certification`.

Let's replace `Certification` with a different type and see if it makes more sense:

```
public T BuildList<T>(T list, AttributeModel model) where T : Animal
{
    return new Animal("", "", "");
}
```

Now what if you called `Dog d = BuildList<Dog>()`? The method will return an `Animal`, not a `Dog`.

The compiler knows that the method is supposed to return a `T` but instead it is returning a `Certification`, which works if `T` *is* `Certification`, but not if `T` is a type that *derives from* `Certification`. You can return a more specific type but not a less specific one:

```
public Dog getThing<Dog>()
{
    return new Animal(); // obviously fails - an Animal is not necessarily a Dog
    return (Dog)(new Animal()); // This will _compile_ but will fail at runtime since the Animal is not a Dog
}

public Animal getThing<Animal>()
{
    return new Dog();  // Dog is a type of Animal so this is fine.
}
```

Whether in your case the return type should just be `Certification` or if you should somehow return an object of type `T` is unclear from the context.

> I read "where T : Certification" to mean that the method can also be read as:
>
> ```
>    public Certification BuildList(Certification list, AttributeModel model)
> ```

this is true only if `T` *is* `Certification` when the method is called. Since it is generic, the method can be called for *any type* that inherits from `Certification`, so if you had

```
public class MyCertification : Certification;
```

and use that for `T` (meaning you call `var o = BuildList<MyCertification>(...)`) the method now effectively becomes:

```
public public MyCertification BuildList(MyCertification list, AttributeModel model) 
{
    return new Certification("", "", "");
}
```

since `Certification` is not a `MyCertification` (in the same way that a generic `Animal` is not a `Dog`), this would fail.

The compiler requires that whatever is returned from the method derives from `T` (NOT `Certification`). since `Certification` would not derived from a type that itself derives from `Certification`, the compiler tells you that the return type is invalid.

Comment: But it's the "return new Certification("", "", "");" failing, not the assignment of the value returned from the method. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: @DavidThielen please explain why do you think it *should* work or what you expect to happen if it would be allowed... The answer answers the question, but apparently it is not what you have problem with...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Updated. And this is interesting. I thought it would be I missed something basic. But it looks like I have a fundamental misunderstanding. And I want to learn what I have wrong. TIA.

Comment: @DavidThielen The method is defined to return a `T` which is a `Certification` or _something that derives from it_. I had hoped that the `Animal` example would make more sense. You can't return a generic `Animal` from a method which is supposed to return a `Dog`.

Comment: @DStanley I'm clearly misunderstanding you. I understand how BuildList<Dog>() returns an animal. The problem I'm having is BuildList<Animal>() cannot return an Animal object. What am I not understanding about this? Please see my second update above.

Comment: I think one source of confusion is the way Visual Studio does feedback on this. When you return the wrong type, it highlights the entire expression you're returning. So if you return "int" and try to return a complex expression that evaluates to a string, that whole thing will get highlighted. Honestly I find it a bit confusing myself but I've now got my brain hardwired to go "does the return type match?".

Comment: Also, imagine you have

TAnimal MyPet<TAnimal>() where TAnimal : Animal { return new Animal() }

now call it with MyPet<Dog>. Then the return type should be a Dog, and Animal is not assignable to Dog. Because you _could_ do that, it prevents you from returning Animal. You have to return TAnimal or a type you can prove to the compiler that derives FROM TAnimal, not Animal.

Comment: @DavidThielen I added some more to my answer, specifically addressing part of your update. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, generics is not the same a template substitution (if you come from a C++ background). Just because you _don't_ call the method with something other than `Certification` doesn't mean that it will still compile. The compiler sees you're trying to make the method generic but are returning a specific type

Comment: Thank you. And I am so glad I asked this question - I now understand generics a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't make T a Certification. It's a wrapper. Consider the following code:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dog = new Dog();
        var cat = new Cat();

        var farm = new AnimalFarmGeneric<Animal>();

        farm.FeedAnimal(dog);
        farm.FeedAnimal(cat);

        var catFarm = new AnimalFarmGeneric<Cat>();
        var strayCat = catFarm.GetAnimal();

        //catFarm.FeedAnimal(strayCat); // compilation error; Animal is not Cat
        farm.FeedAnimal(strayCat); // works, strayCat is Animal
    }

    public class AnimalFarmGeneric<T> where T : Animal
    {
        public T FeedAnimal(T animal)
        {
            animal.Feed();
            return animal;
        }

        // examples for showing difference in IL
        public T GetAnimalGeneric()
        {
            return (T)new Animal(); // Fails if T is Dog or Cat
        }

        public Animal GetAnimal()
        {
            return new Animal();
        }

    }

    public class Animal
    {
        public bool IsHungry = true;

        public virtual void Feed()
        {
            IsHungry = false;
        }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override void Feed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fed animal dog food.");
            base.Feed();
        }
    }

    public class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override void Feed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fed animal cat food");
            base.Feed();
        }
    }
}
```

If we look at the IL generated for GetAnimal and GetAnimalGeneric, you will see they are different return types.

GetAnimal:

```
.method public hidebysig instance class ScratchConsole.Program/Animal 
        GetAnimal() cil managed
{
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (class ScratchConsole.Program/Animal V_0) <-- Concrete Type
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ScratchConsole.Program/Animal::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009
  IL_0009:  ldloc.0
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method AnimalFarmGeneric`1::GetAnimal
```

GetAnimalGeneric:

```
.method public hidebysig instance !T  GetAnimalGeneric() cil managed
{
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init (!T V_0) <---- Generic Type
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void ScratchConsole.Program/Animal::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  unbox.any  !T <---- unboxing
  IL_000b:  stloc.0
  IL_000c:  br.s       IL_000e
  IL_000e:  ldloc.0
  IL_000f:  ret
} // end of method AnimalFarmGeneric`1::GetAnimalGeneric
```

The confusion for me seems to be that when you use where T : Certification it is easy to read that as T is a Certification. It's really means that T and Certification are assignment compatible. The [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_6th_edition_june_2012.pdf) goes into this further than I can.