# return a list of interfaced objects

Tags: java, list, generics, interface, return

I have a class `Category` that implements the interface `CategoryManager`. Next there is `Card` that maintains a `List<Category>`.

Now I would like to return this list, but with categories as `CategoryManager`, hence `List<CategoryManager>`. The reason I'm doing this is that the "public interface" of `Category` is extremly ugly, and I'd like to narrow it down by showing the outside user only the clean `CategoryManager`.

How do I do this?

I've come up with the following method:

```
public <T extends CategoryManager> List<T> getAllCategories() {
          return (List<T>) categories; //with categories beeing List<Category>
```

}

It does work,but I find it rather ugly, bacause I'm casting to and returning `List<T>` here, thus losing information and... Well, I think you'll sgree that it's not pretty for various reasons.

Can anyone come with a better/nicer solution?

Regards :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a generic collection to base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539287/casting-a-generic-collection-to-base-type)

Comment: @Will A - This is Java, not C#.

Comment: @Justin - good point, my apologies - comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same point holds as holds in the .NET example. You should not cast between collection types. It works because of Java's [erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). I would be a little surprised if you were not getting a warning from the cast though.

The most accurate option is:

```
public List<? extends CategoryManager> getAllCategories()
{
    return categories;
}
```

The negative is that `List<CategoryManager>` is not the same as `List<? extends CategoryManager>`. However, it does match the suggested intent of the method name.

Comment: Why, yes this does look nicer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `<T extends CategoryManager>` bit, which makes `getAllCategories` a [generic method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). This will work just fine:

```
public class Category implements CategoryManager
{   
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

    public List<? extends CategoryManager> getAllCategories()
    {
        return categories;
    }
}
```