# How to cast list of descendant objects to list of parent objects without creating new list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Casting a generic collection to base type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539287/casting-a-generic-collection-to-base-type)

I have a class A and a class B that inherits from class A.

In another class I have a List and I would like to return it as a List but without creating a new List because I want to use an observable collection and need both lists to be the same.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can't; lists are invariant, even in 4.0. The `IEnumerable<...>` interface is supports variance, though - but that would give you full observable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an `IEnumerable<>` instead of `List<>`? Then your property can return `BaseCollectionName.Select(a => (B)a)`, and you don't actually have to make a new List?

Otherwise, there's no simple way of casting `List<A>` to `List<B>` without making a new `List<>` object.

Comment: Why are there so many questions in your answer?

Comment: Probably because I'm proposing making deeper architectural changes (and possibly making some assumptions), and they may, for some reason, not jive with what OP is going for...