# C# base class as parameter type

Tags: c#

I have two classes as follows, and Class A inherits from Class B.

```
public class A
{
     public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class B: A
{

}
```

Then I have a function as follows which takes in a list of items of class A:

```
public static void Get(List<A> values)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Now when I try to pass a list of items of Class B, into the function as follows,

```
private function void Test()
{
     var k = new List<B>();
     Get(k);
}
```

I get the following error message

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<B>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<A>'

Should this not work as B just inherits from A and will have the properties that A has?

I have already spent hours trying to look this up, but I have not been to figure out what I an doing wrong. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is that `function` suppose to be there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a generic collection to base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539287/casting-a-generic-collection-to-base-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it should not. It is potentially unsafe:

```
class C : A {

}

public static void Get(List<A> values)
{
    values.Add(new C());
}
```

If you were to call `Get` with `new List<B>()`, it would be unsafe, as you'd be inserting instances of `C` in `List<B>`.

It would be safe, however, if `List<T>` was a "read-only" interface, in which case *covariance*, which is what you are looking for, would be safe. You can change `List<A>` to `IEnumerable<A>` instead and it'll work.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and providing the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Although `B` can be used everywhere an `A` can be, the `List<B>` and `List<A>` are not [*covariant*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). However, starting with .NET 4.0 you can use a list of `Derived` class in place of `IEnumerable<Base>`. So if you declare your function to take `IEnumerable<A>` rather than `List<A>`, your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

B does inherit from A, but that doesn't mean that `List<B>` Inherits from `List<A>` 
You should just put the B objects into a `List<A>` and pass that to the method.  This is what polymorphism is all about.

```
  private function void Test()
  {
      var k = new List<A>();
      k.Add(new B());
      k.Add(new B());
      k.Add(new B());
      k.Add(new B());
      k.Add(new B());
      k.Add(new B());
      Get(k);
  }
```